# what the buddha said about his own karma?

Tags: personal-practice, karma, reality

I have a strong believe in buddha but i am not much in karma logic. Had the buddha said anything of karma? If yes then what and if not then how? I am seeing some people getting back in a very amazing way whatever they had done in their respective past. Sometimes it is related to extreme past events, even. Like having a generation gap, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> what the buddha said about his own karma?

The Buddha mentioned that there were 8 past Karma which were effective even after becoming Buddha. See: [Why the Buddha Suffered - Apadāna 39.10](http://www.ancient-buddhist-texts.net/English-Texts/Why-the-Buddha-Suffered/Why-the-Buddha-Suffered.pdf)

> but i am not much in karma logic.

Karma is one of the things that only a Buddha completely understands. We can only have a rough idea of its operation.

> I am seeing some people getting back in a very amazing way whatever they had done in their respective past.

Even outside Buddhism there is a saying your past catches up with you. In the Buddhist perspective this is termed Karma.

> Sometimes it is related to extreme past events, even.

There are [5 Niyamas](http://buddhism.about.com/od/basicbuddhistteachings/tp/The-Five-Niyamas.htm) or causal factors which define your experiences and also being in the wrong place the wrong time and the right place in the right time, i.e., random events. So past Karma or action does not dictate all results.

> Like having a generation gap

I do not think the generation gap has anything to do with Karma. This is more to do with social, technological and attitude changes.

Comment: I believe in karma. I said my curiousity, someone try answer.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Karma is one of the main teaching in Buddhism. Basically what buddhism teach us is this. We are in a wrong understanding of me. Even thought we thinks there is something called me, the truth is there is no anything called me. (At least there is not a define constant thing)

Because of this wrong understanging, we are doing 'things' which were not existed before and we become the owner of this 'things'. These 'things' have re-acts.

e.x. Say we kill a moquito. This incident of 'killing that mosquito' was never before. We did it. Hence we are the owner of that incident. This killing incident has a negative power which will make us suffer. So we will suffer for that incident in future. The power of incident came from the strength of our own thoughts and from the act. (First we are thinking we want to kill this mosquito, then we think to kill it, then we do the act) This is simply what Karma is.

For each and every thing we are doing, this law applies. Lord Buddha describes, this same law plus the miss understanding I mentioned above cause us to born over and over again. Each time as of the Karma we did for the rebirth.

Main aim of buddhism is get the right understanding and stop these re-births.

Answer (score 2):

*Pardon me my direct knowledge is not that clear on the issue so let me forward you to the very teachings themselves.....*

---

*These are the Sutras / Suttas By Lord Buddha on Karma.*

[**Maha Kammavibhanga Sutta: The Great Exposition of Kamma**](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.136.nymo.html)

**[Cula-kammavibhanga Sutta: The Shorter Exposition of Kamma](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.135.nymo.html)**

---

Go to this link and look for "**Vimanavatthu**" (Contains good returns of Karma)

**[Khuddaka Nikaya: The Collection of Little Texts](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/)**

---

This Contains bad returns of bad karma

[**Khuddaka Nikaya - Petavatthu - The Real Truth of Life**](http://realtruthlife.blogspot.com/2011/05/khuddaka-nikaya-petavatthu.html)